# Count rows in table that contain specific span

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do I could the number of rows in a table that contain a span with specific text?

For example, from the below table, how would I count the number of rows that have a span that says 'User'?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="CorrectionCodesList">
    <tr>
        <td>            
            <span class="label label-primary">Print</span>
            Zoning is not answered
        </td>
    </tr>              

    <tr>
        <td>            
            <span class="label label-primary">User</span>
            Vehicle Type is required
        </td>
    </tr>              

    <tr>
        <td>            
            <span class="label label-primary">Do Not Print</span>
            Business Phone Number is required
        </td>
    </tr>              

    <tr>
        <td>            
            <span class="label label-primary">Print</span>
            Business Email Address is required
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a filter on the TDs to see if they contain a span with text() == "User" etc:

### JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6JW3M/

```
var $rows = $('#CorrectionCodesList tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('td span').text() == "User";
});
alert($rows.length);
```

Note: This specific logic assumes 1 span only inside the TD as `find().text()` will only return the text of the first match.

**Littel update:** I tend to use scoped jQuery selectors as they will usually result in shorter code e.g:

```
var $rows = $('#CorrectionCodesList tr').filter(function(){
    return $('td span',this).text() == "User";
});
alert($rows.length);
```

Comment: +1 However, why are you finding the span in the filter function? The initial selector could just be `$('#CorrectionCodesList tr td span')` right?

Comment: @Curt in the end, he want the row, not the span.

Comment: @Curt: No, they are counting rows so it must be this way. I could remove the `td` from `td span`, but this is meant to be instructional :)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The easiest solution would be to use `:has` and `:contains()`:</strike>

You could use `:has` and `:contains()`:

```
var numberOfTr = $('tr:has(span:contains(User))').length
```

**However**, it is case sensitive and word like *"User-interface"* are matched...

You should use filter on the `tr` with a more restrictive match :

```
var $tr = $('tr').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).find('span').text()).toLowerCase() === 'user'
});

alert($tr.length)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mfx8S/

Comment: `contains` is not an exact match (which was specified)

Comment: This won't work if OP wishes to not include span's with a value of "User1" etc.

Comment: @curt, didn't see about the restrictive part, but was writing a better code, updated.